# How to get all friend using Facebook v4

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm using Facebook v4.0.1 to integrate into my app. I using FBSDKGraphRequest to get friend list

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *friendsRequest = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me/friends" parameters:nil];
    FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection = [[[FBSDKGraphRequestConnection alloc] init] autorelease];
    [connection addRequest:friendsRequest
         completionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *innerConnection, NSDictionary *result, NSError *error) {

         }];
    // start the actual request
    [connection start];
```

It just returns around 25 friends and a param named paging to get next friends.

How can I use paging to get next or there is another way to get all friends once

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"paging": {
     "previous": "me/friends?limit=25&before=NDMyNzQyODI3OTQw"
"next": "me/friends?limit=25&after=MTAxNTExOTQ1MjAwNzI5NDE="
}
```

The paging should include a "next" & "previous" URLs, you will want to use those URLs in-place of your original @"me/friends" string and you'll get either the page before or after the current data.  If there is no longer a "next" that means that there are no more pages for you to request.

You could always try adding the limit parameter on to your first request and see what happens when you up the 25 limit to something higher.  I'm not sure how many you'll be able to get away with getting at one time but at least it's an upper limit so it'll return what it can if it's over.

More paging info available here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3#paging

Comment: I not get it, the link of the next field is "https: //graph.facebook.com/v2.3/1445243049/friends?format=json&access_token=...&limit=25&offset=25&__after_id=enc_Ad...JS". I wonder I use facebook sdk v4.0.1, why the link is v2.3. I use this link, but it not returns friends

Comment: I use the url "me/friends?limit=25&offset=nextOffset". nextOffset will be increased 25 after each time get friend. But it just allows me to do it 2 times, until the third time it not has the "next" field anymore although I get more than 500 friends.

Comment: It can be a little confusing at first, iOS Facebook SDK v4 refers to the iOS libraries and API's that you will use (obj-c or swift).  OpenGraph v2.3 will give you the endpoints (string URLs & parameters) to call on Facebooks servers to get information.

The OpenGraph documentation for me/friends it has this under permissions: "This will only return any friends who have used (via Facebook Login) the app making the request."  So this explains why you are not seeing all 500 of your friends.

[Open-Graph Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/user/friends)

Comment: If you are signed into your developer facebook account you can also see this in the [Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)  "me/friends/?limit=5000" returns me only the 9 friends who have used the Graph API Explorer, not my 600+ friends.  This was a change in OpenGraph when they moved from v1 to v2, v2 focuses more on privacy and exposing less data to everyone.

Comment: Thanks, so you mean there is no way to get all of my friend list? if so, it very bad for my app. Is there any way for me to achieve all

Comment: Up until a few days ago if you had an existing app you could use the older version of the graph API & get all an user's friends but it was shut down in April.  You might be able to accomplish something similar using the "me/taggable_friends" but you have to go through the Facebook review process first.  Other than that, you are probably out of luck sorry!

Comment: Thanks, I now can get all friends using taggable_friends  permission. I will submit to get approval from facebook

Comment: Can you fix this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30067252/how-to-get-all-friend-using-facebook-v4

Answer (score 15):

The accepted answer got me in the right direction but it's not 100% correct.

### Request

For FacebookSDK 4.x using graph v2.3, you now only get 25 results back unless you up your limit. The max limit you can choose is 1k. Here's an example for getting 100:

```
NSMutableString *facebookRequest = [NSMutableString new];
[facebookRequest appendString:@"/me/friends"];
[facebookRequest appendString:@"?limit=100"];

FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                  initWithGraphPath:facebookRequest
                                  parameters:nil
                                  HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:<YOUR BLOCK HERE>];
```

Note - YOUR_BLOCK_HERE is the block you'll use to process results.

### Paging

Now comes the question of paging. The JSON code that was pasted in the accepted answer is not correct. Here's what the JSON looks like for /me/friends:

```
data =     (
            {
        id = 1234567890123456711;
        name = “John Snow";
    },
            {
        id = 1234567891234567891;
        name = “Ned Stark";
    }
);
paging =     {
    next = "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/<FB_USER_ID>/friends?limit=100&format=json&access_token=<SESSION_TOKEN>&offset=100&__after_id=enc_asdfasas2393nfaASDVASEqwe";
};
summary =     {
    "total_count" = 175;
};
```

We know from this JSON result from Facebook, that we need to continue paging because of the following two reasons: 1.) We have Graph results in the data portion 2.) We got a next url.

Note - SESSION_TOKEN is the current session token that made the request.

Note - FB_USER_ID is the Facebook ID of the user who made the request.

Now this is how you perform the request for 'next' page. You must remove the Facebook URL if you are going to use the FBSDKGraphRequest.

```
NSString *nextUrl = [pagingDictionary objectForKey:@"next"];

//remove the 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.3/'
nextUrl = [nextUrl substringFromIndex:32];

FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                              initWithGraphPath:nextUrl
                                              parameters:nil
                                              ];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:<YOUR_BLOCK_HERE>];
```

### Tip

Write your code so the facebook paging is either called using recursive block calls or recursive method calls. I obviously simplified my post to focus on the question asked. This way you can write the block parsing code once and reuse it for different type of paged requests like 'me/friends' or 'me/invitable_friends'.

Comment: I am using only one friend name. but total count is 3

Answer (score -1):

You try this code

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                               initWithGraphPath:@"/me/friends"
                                      parameters:params
                                      HTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                      id result,
                                      NSError *error) {
    // Handle the result
}];
```

[enter link description here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/friends)